# Cannot build app on android. Multiple Linking errors

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

when building my app on android studio, I'm getting the following error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":527,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":39038,"endLine":592,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":43834}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:528:5-593:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":641,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":46880,"endLine":698,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":51129}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:642:5-699:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":747,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":54189,"endLine":811,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":58892}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:748:5-812:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":908,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":64921,"endLine":965,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":69086}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:909:5-966:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1022,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":72626,"endLine":1033,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":73681}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:1023:5-1034:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":426}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":431,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":652}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":12,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":657,"endLine":15,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":891}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":442}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":447,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":684}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":37,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2618,"endLine":40,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2837}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:38:5-41:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/hyphenationFrequency' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":37,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2618,"endLine":40,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2837}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:38:5-41:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/breakStrategy' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":44,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":3177,"endLine":47,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":3402}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:45:5-48:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/hyphenationFrequency' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":44,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":3177,"endLine":47,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":3402}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/102f4e5339e61a836806a4922c0ccf33/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:45:5-48:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/breakStrategy' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cb98cb7aa050aadd68368dde2f298c4f/cardview-1.0.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":4,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":200}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cb98cb7aa050aadd68368dde2f298c4f/cardview-1.0.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:3:5-5:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":1708,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":117184,"endLine":1715,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":117611}}],"original":"/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a72fc6914174c60e99bb51c1d98759b9/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:1709:5-1716:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I also tried https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30815, but still getting the same error. How to fix this?

Comment: Did your try to sync your Gradle project? When you open the gradle menu from the right sidebar of Android Studio, you can eaload all gradle files with the button "reload gradle project"

Comment: could you provide a link to your project on github?

Comment: @Anatolii no sorry.

Comment: @zendevil.eth did you manage to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by cleaning the project Gradle.

Run Below Command:

```
cd android
rm -rf android/.gradle
rm -rf .gradle
rm -rf ~/.gradle
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: Getting the same error after following this

Comment: Please try again i have updated my answer.

Comment: ./gradlew clean gives: zsh: no such file or directory: ./gradlew

Comment: I forgot to navigate to the android directory please try again I have updated my answer

Comment: still getting the same error after following the steps

Comment: have you run all commands and the gradle downloaded?

Comment: yes, ran all the commands and gradle was downloaded

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches and restart by using android studio ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230808/discussion-between-lamp-bottle-and-jignesh-mayani).

Answer (score 0):

Goto Android folder and Run `./gradlew clean`

Remove caches folder from `/Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/`

And Go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrappers.properties` and replace `distrubution url` to 6.3 instead of 6.2 like this,

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

NOTE: check targetSdkVersion in `build.gradle`, it should be greater than 26.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you are inheriting the wrong theme in `styles.xml`. Make sure you are using the correct App Theme. I Can't show you the exact code seeing your post but that's the problem I can see.